# Django: Filtering a queryset then count

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to limit the number of queries I perform on a page. The queryset returns the objects created within the last 24 hours. I then want to filter that queryset to count the objects based upon a field.

Example:

```
cars = self.get_queryset()
volvos_count = cars.filter(brand="Volvo").count()
mercs_count = cars.filter(brand="Merc").count()
```

With an increasing number of brands (in this example), the number of queries grows linearly with the number of brands that must be queried.

How can you make a single query for the cars that returns a dict of all of the unique values for brand and the number of instances within the queryset?

Result:

```
{'volvos': 4, 'mercs': 50, ...}
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Of the comments so far, they have been close but not quite on the mark. Using a `values_list('brand', flat=True)` will return the brands. From there you can use

```
 from collections import Counter
```

To return the totals. It would be great if there is a way to do this from a single query, but maybe it isn't possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a count for each distinct brand, you use `values` in conjunction with `annotate`.

```
totals = cars.values('brand').annotate(Count('brand'))
```

This gives you a queryset, each of whose elements is a dictionary with `brand` and `brand__count`. You can convert that directly into a dict with the format you want:

```
{item['brand']: item['brand__count'] for item in totals}
```

Comment: That is close, it seems like one way to do this is just queryset.values_list('brand', flat=True) and then use Counter on the result. That will return the value & count that I was looking for.

Comment: Using Counter would indeed work - but would get really slow once you started getting a significant amount of results. That sort of work is much better suited to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT brand, COUNT(*) as total 
FROM cars 
GROUP BY brand 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Equivalent:

`cars.objects.all().values('brand').annotate(total=Count('brand')).order_by('total')`